# Document properties don't sync from library item to Word document

Tags: document-library, document

I have created document property placeholders from quick parts by opening the document from the document library. As I'm able to see the changes getting reflected in the document when I update the document library item in the library and vice versa.

But when I download and upload the same document from the working library to a exactly similar document library which has the same content type attached some how the data is NOT syncing and it is showing the same old data.

When I checked the document properties panel it shows the data which is in the item which means data is being synced to the document, but not to the placeholders.

Any pointers on why this is happening will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this content type created by Visual Studio?

Comment: yes, why is there any problem with content types created by VS ??

Comment: Could you please enlight me on this? I also have this problem, but I don't understand the solution. I'm using sharepoint Online. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My team had the exact issue that you're describing and they resolved it by adding **SourceID** property to site columns which are a part of content type.

Unfortunately, there is no more information on our team wiki about this issue, so I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: Oh yeahh i was not mentioning the SourceID field my sitecolumns... it worked :D thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work by replacing the custom library columns by custom site columns created in the primary site. This way I can move the document between libraries and subsites, as long as all libraries have the site columns in question.